# HTML attribute "class" into <select> <option> tags generated via DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have generated a dropdownlist like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ExternalSystems, new SelectList(Model.ExternalSystems, "Id", "Name"), "All systems", new {@class = "param-select", id = "val-external-system"})
```

and the result is as follows:

```
<select class="param-select" id="val-external-systems" name="ExternalSystems">
    <option value="">All systems</option>
    <option value="0">ExtSystem1</option>
    <option value="1">ExtSystem2</option>
</select>
```

But I need the result to be as below:

```
<select class="param-select" id="val-external-systems" name="ExternalSystems">
    <option value="" **class="select-default"**>All systems</option>
    <option value="0">ExtSystem1</option>
    <option value="1">ExtSystem2</option>
</select>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible by HTMLx standarts. Html option tag is not supported "class" attribute.

if you want any option selected, should use to "selected" attribute. example:

```
<select class="param-select" id="val-external-systems" name="ExternalSystems">
<option value="" selected>All systems</option>
<option value="0">ExtSystem1</option>
<option value="1">ExtSystem2</option>
```

example with Razor syntax ("All System" option is selected as default):

```
@Html.DropDownList("ExternalSystems", new SelectList(Model.ExternalSystems, "Id", "Name"), "All systems", new { @class="param-select" })
```

Comment: An actual quote of the specification, stating that it is not allowed, would be nice. I have not found anything proving this (yet).

Comment: This is entirely false.  By the HTMLx standards you've mentioned class is allowed on any HTML tag.  http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#classes